# Check if a student will pass an MCQ exam with negative marking

Tags: analysis

Here is a scenario:
We have an MCQ exam with 100 questions.

Every 3 wrong answers will remove 1 correct answer.

The Minimum needed score to pass this exam is 50

I'm using the following formula :
score = ( (correct * 3) - wrong) / (3 * total)) * 100;

now, I will calculate the student's score on each question, at what point should I decided that this student will not pass the exam no matter what he would do on the remaining questions?

I have not slept for almost 96 hours and I can't think clearly at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the student answers all the questions, and the number of questions answered correctly is $r$ and the number answered incorrectly is $w$ we have $$r+w=100$$ and in order to pass, the student needs $$r-\frac w3\geq50$$  Eliminating $w$ gives $r\geq 62.5$ and since $r$ must be an integer, we have $r\geq63$, which implies $w\leq37$.  When the student has answered $38$ questions incorrectly, there is no possibility that he will pass.

The foregoing only applies if the student answers all the questions, but a student may skip some questions.  I think the easiest thing to do is to keep a running score.  If the student has answered $r$ questions correctly, $w$ incorrectly, and skipped $s$ questions, his score up to this point is $$r-\frac w3$$ and there are $100-r-w-s$ questions remaining, so the highest score he can possibly achieve is $$r-\frac w3+100-r-w-s=100-s-\frac{4w}{3}$$ If this is less than $50$, the student has no chance.  Furthermore, the minimum number of questions he must answer correctly in order to pass is $50$ minus his current score, round up to the next integer, if necessary.

For example, suppose the student has seen $60$ questions, answered $40$ correctly, skipped $15$, and answered $5$ wrong.  The student's score to this point is $$40-\frac53=38.333$$ so the student needs to answer at least $12$ more questions correctly.

If it were me, I would be reluctant to tell a student, "You must answer at least $12$ more questions correctly in order to pass," for fear he would interpret it, or at least say he interpreted it, as "If you answer at least $12$ more questions correctly, you will pass," which isn't true, since he might answer $12$ right and $28$ wrong.  I would rather show the current score and the number of questions remaining.  Then if a student sees that his current score is $40$ and there are only $9$ questions remaining, he will easily understand that he has no possibility of reaching $50$ and passing.

Comment: Thank you, now is there a way to calculate his chance that he would pass before answering the  38th wrong question?

Comment: Not unless we know the probabilities of his answering the questions correctly.  You can't just calculate probabilities out of thin air.

Comment: What if we assume that he would give the correct answer?

Comment: What does that mean?  Correct answer to what?  The next question?  All the subsequent questions?  I say it again.  Unless we know the probabilities of his answering the various questions correctly, there is no way of computing the probability of his passing.  I may also say, that if I were a student, and I found out that you had terminated my exam when there was still a possibility, however slight, that I could pass, I would be very angry indeed, and I would take whatever avenues were open to me to make you regret it.

Comment: at this point you are my hero don't get me wrong, to answer you, yes let's assume that he would give the correct answer to all the subsequent questions.
I want to show him the chance that he would pass the exam.

Comment: Ah, I understand finally.  I'll add some more detail to my answer.

Comment: You are a legend, thank you

Comment: Oops, one more thing.  Is he allowed to skip a question?  So that it counts neither for him nor against him?

Comment: yes he can skip a question

Comment: I'm going to have to revise my answer then, because we don't have $r+w=100.$  It may be a little while.

Comment: I don't how to thank you at this point! this means a lot for me

Comment: Thank you very much, I got what i needed. wish i could buy you a beer